# Understanding how to subscribe to async observables

Tags: angular, rxjs

When my application loads, I need to call an API and save the results. I'm doing this in a service. I'd like to then use the service in a component. Specifically, when there are any changes to what has been saved, I'd like to update the component that uses it. I'm trying to implement this via Observables but don't understand how to save the response from the API as such.

In the service I have  this:

```
fetchAPI() {
      return this.http.get(`${this.baseURL}/endpoint`)
        .map(res => res.json())
        .do(data => {
          this.APIRes = data;
        });
  }
```

where `this.APIRes`is `APIRes: Object[];`

How can I then 'subscribe' to the service's `APIRes` in a component.

I've tried changing `APIRes`'s type to `Observable<Object[]>;` but then can't seem to push new data to the `service.APIRes` The .next option isn't available.

Thanks

Comment: Well if you want to store the data in service and from there share the fetched data across your app, you would perhaps want to store it in a behaviorsubject instead, to which the components would subscribe to.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `this.APIRes` will not be an `Observable`, as it's simply the result of your `GET` request.

However, the `fetchAPI` function will return an `Observable`, so you can subscribe to that

Comment: So basically my issue is that I'm trying to combine asynchronous http with sync between components

Comment: You simply need to listen to the change within your component (perhaps using the angular `OnChanges` lifecycle hook?), and then save as you would usually